# Visual studio Test Explorer Group by name Namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, test-explorer

Is that possible to group the tests by namespace in Visual studio 2015 Test Explorer?

In the blog - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/08/05/evolving-the-visual-studio-test-platform-part-2/

Snapshot - https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/08/GroupingAndDuration.jpg shows GroupBy dropdown with namespace. But I do not find it in Visual Studio 2015.

Is there a way, I can get a tree view of my tests?

Comment: I have Visual studio 2015 update 3 (Professional)

Comment: I recently stumbled upon [AxoCover](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=axodox1.AxoCover) which is a test runner that groups tests by project and namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Visual Studio 2017 has the namespace option, but my Visual Studio 2015 does not. I think they left it out in 2015.